# Renaming file using box api v1

Tags: box-api

It's possible to rename the file while uploading to my account in box.net?
I'm using the 1.0 version and the next url:

https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/upload/myauth/myfolderid?share=1

I know it's possible to rename the file using ajax but there's nothing in the API, a option like "share" for example, to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to rename the file and upload in the same API call in V1, but you can rename the file with a second API call: http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923947/ApiFunction_rename